# Printing out results in case of object relational table (Oracle)

Tags: java, oracle, object

This is how I print out results in the standard relational table using JAVA. However I am using a object-relational table.

```
 public static void results_view () 
    throws SQLException 
    { String sql = 
      "SELECT * from House";
    try { Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection 
("jdbc:default:connection:");
      PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      ResultSet rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
      printResults(rset);
      rset.close();
      pstmt.close(); 
      } 
    catch (SQLException e) {System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }  
  }

 static void printResults (ResultSet rset) 
   throws SQLException { String buffer = "";
    try { ResultSetMetaData meta = rset.getMetaData();
      int cols = meta.getColumnCount(), rows = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= cols; i++) 
       {
        int size = meta.getPrecision(i);
        String label = meta.getColumnLabel(i);
        if (label.length() > size) size = label.length();
        while (label.length() < size) label += " ";
        buffer = buffer + label + "  "; }
        buffer = buffer + "\n";
        while (rset.next()) {
      rows++;
      for (int i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
          int size = meta.getPrecision(i);
          String label = meta.getColumnLabel(i);
          String value = rset.getString(i);
          if (label.length() > size) size = label.length();
          while (value.length() < size) value += " ";
          buffer = buffer + value + "  ";  }
          buffer = buffer + "\n";   }
          if (rows == 0) buffer = "No data found!\n";
         System.out.println(buffer); } 
    catch (SQLException e) {System.err.println(e.getMessage());}  }
```

How do I print out the results in case of object relational table?

My case bellow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Boat AS OBJECT(
Name varchar2(30),
Ident number,
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Type_boats AS TABLE OF Boat;

CREATE TABLE HOUSE(
Name varchar2(40),
MB Type_boats)
NESTED TABLE MB store as P_Boat;

INSERT INTO House VALUES ('Name',Type_boats(Boat('Boat1', 1)));
```

I also have the package written with the procedure to call, which looks like this..

```
CRATE OR REPLACE package House_boats
PROCEDURE add(everything works here)
PROCEDURE results_view;
END House_boats;

CREATE OR REPLACE Package.body House_boats AS
PROCEDURE add(everything works here) AS LANGUAGE JAVA
Name House_boats.add(...)

PROCEDURE results_view AS LANGUAGE JAVA
Name House_boats.resuts_view();
END House_boats;
```

So yeah, basicly I just don't know how to print them out in case of objects.

I call it out using:

```
CALL House_boats.results_view();  <<< nothing works here.
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` writes to standard out.  I don't what you were imagining would happen, but in an Oracle database standard out and error write to the trace files.

If you want to re-direct your Java output to a screen you need to use DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/chseven.htm#JJDEV13285)

Comment: What I need to do is call out a procedure in ORACLE (created in JAVA) to output results of the table. 

For example: "CALL House_boats.add(values here); < adds values to my House table" (which I got working btw) and
"CALL House_boats.results_view();" to OUTPUT all fields of the table "HOUSE" - the same way that I could have used "SELECT * FROM TABLE or SELECT VALUE(A) from House A;  So...  What I don't know how to do is output results in case of object-relational table, cause it works fine when it's relational table (without objects in it), - when this is not the case.